# Custom Woocommerce Payment Gateway Not Showing on Checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am in the process of creating a plugin to integrate a custom WooCommerce payment gateway. Although I have successfully activated it in the admin panel but the payment option does not yet appear on the checkout page.

WooCommerce version: 8.4.0

WordPress version: 6.4.2

Here is the complete code of  my plugin

```
if (!defined("ABSPATH")) {
    exit(); // Exit if accessed directly.
}

// Hook to plugins_loaded to ensure WooCommerce is loaded
add_action("plugins_loaded", "init_woocommerce_to_stripe", 0);

function init_woocommerce_to_stripe()
{
    if (!class_exists("WC_Payment_Gateway")) {
        return;
    }

    // Define the custom payment gateway class
    class WC_Gateway_WooCommerce_To_Stripe extends WC_Payment_Gateway
    {
        // Declare properties
        public $redirect_url;

        public function __construct()
        {
            // Basic setup for the gateway
            $this->id = "woocommerce_to_stripe";
            $this->has_fields = false;
            $this->icon = "";
            $this->method_title = "WooCommerce to Stripe";
            $this->method_description =
                "Redirects users to a custom URL with order ID and total amount for Stripe payments.";
            $this->supports = [];

            // Initialize settings
            $this->init_form_fields();
            $this->init_settings();

            // Get settings values
            $this->title = $this->get_option("title");
            $this->description = $this->get_option("description");
            $this->enabled = $this->get_option("enabled");

            // Use the constructor to set dynamic properties
            $this->redirect_url = $this->get_option(
                "redirect_url",
                "https://www.example.com/"
            ); // Default redirect URL

            // Save settings on WooCommerce admin options update
            add_action(
                "woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_" . $this->id,
                [$this, "process_admin_options"]
            );
        }

        // Define form fields for WooCommerce settings
        public function init_form_fields()
        {
            $this->form_fields = [
                "enabled" => [
                    "title" => "Enable/Disable",
                    "type" => "checkbox",
                    "label" => "Enable WooCommerce to Stripe",
                    "default" => "yes",
                ],
                "title" => [
                    "title" => "Title",
                    "type" => "text",
                    "description" =>
                        "This controls the title which the user sees during checkout.",
                    "default" => "WooCommerce to Stripe",
                    "desc_tip" => true,
                ],
                "description" => [
                    "title" => "Description",
                    "type" => "textarea",
                    "description" =>
                        "This controls the description which the user sees during checkout.",
                    "default" =>
                        "Redirects users to a custom URL with order ID and total amount for Stripe payments.",
                ],
                "redirect_url" => [
                    "title" => "Redirect URL",
                    "type" => "text",
                    "description" =>
                        "Enter the custom URL where users will be redirected with order ID and total amount.",
                    "default" => "https://www.example.com/",
                ],
            ];
        }

        // Process payment and redirect to the custom URL
        public function process_payment($order_id)
        {
            $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

            // Redirect URL with order ID and total amount as query parameters
            $redirect_url =
                $this->redirect_url .
                "?order_id=" .
                $order_id .
                "&total_amount=" .
                $order->get_total();

            return [
                "result" => "success",
                "redirect" => $redirect_url,
            ];
        }
    }

    // Register the custom payment gateway class
    function add_woocommerce_to_stripe_gateway($gateways)
    {
        $gateways[] = "WC_Gateway_WooCommerce_To_Stripe";

        return $gateways;
    }

    // Filter to add the custom payment gateway class
    add_filter(
        "woocommerce_payment_gateways",
        "add_woocommerce_to_stripe_gateway",
        999
    );
}
```